# Vectorized replacement of a subset of a vector

Tags: r, vectorization

Simple question: I've got two vectors of 0's and 1's, `a` and `b`. The `b` vector has as many entries as there are 1's in `a`. I would like to replace the 1's in `a` with the entries from `b`. Of course I can do this in a for loop, but is there a nice vectorized way to do this?

From

```
a <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
b <- c(1, 0, 1)
```

create

```
c <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple: `a[a == 1] <- b`

Comment: I've been trying recently to use `subset()` instead of brackets. Guess I'm trying a bit too hard. Thanks.